# Force interpreting of directives as text?

Tags: java, escaping, velocity

I am using Java and an Apache Velocity template to generate some C code. Currently I have to escape `#define` preprocessor directives, as Apache Velocity also uses this directive. Is it possible to tell Apache Velocity not to interpret `#define` as a directive for Velocity without always having to escape `#define`?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

VTL directives can be escaped with the backslash character ("\") in a manner similar to valid VTL references.

```
\#define will renders texts as #define
```

#define

```
## \#include( "a.txt" ) renders as #include( "a.txt" )
```

#include( "a.txt" )

For more, information:
[Escaping VTL directives](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#escaping_vtl_directives)